# Xpages Repeat return Multiple Array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, xpages, repeat, xpages-ssjs

I think I want something impossible, but I'll give it a try.

I have the following code:

```
<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="rowData" repeatControls="false" indexVar="index">
<xp:this.value>
    <![CDATA[#{javascript:var value1 = docDocument.getItemValue("DocInternNume");
    var toStr1 = value1.toString().replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",");

    var value2 = docDocument.getItemValue("DocIntern");
    var toStr2 = value2.toString().replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",");

    var ar = new Array(2);
    for(var x =0; x<ar.length;x++)
    {
       ar[x] = new Array(toStr1.length)
       for(var y=0;y<toStr1.length;y++){
           if(x==0){
              ar[x][y] = toStr1[y];
           }
           if(x==1){
               ar[x][y] = toStr2[y];
           }
       }
    }

    return ar;}]]></xp:this.value>
    <xp:link escape="true" id="link2" text="#{javascript:rowData;}"
        value="#{javascript:rowData;}">
    </xp:link>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
</xp:repeat>
```

**Code explanation:**

A repeat control which takes as value 2 fields which have:

1st has a String array containing some Names;

2nd has a String array containing the docID;

After that, I am saving those field values in a multidimensional array, length of 2 which I return as the repeat value.

**Why do I return a multidimensional array in the repeat:**

In the repeat as you can see in the above code I have a link which `label` I want to take the value of the 1st field (the Names) and the `URL` I want to take the value of the 2nd field (the docID).

**Why?** because I want to give the user the capability to select some documents in a parent document and after, in a repeat to show the links to the child documents.

***Question:*** is there a way to return a multidimensional array within a repeat and then give to the `label` for eg: rowData[0] and to the `URL` the rowData[1] value? Or is there another way I can achieve this?

As far as I could do the repeat only returns an array.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not use nested repeat controls?  An outer repeat and in inner repeat?

For instance have an outer repeat of documents...  then an inner repeat of a multi value field for each document?

the inner repeat uses the varName of the outer

So if you had 
RepeatOuter  - varName = outerData

you then could do:
    repeatInner - varName = innerData
     BUT when you build the inner repeat... you have whatever is in "outerData" available for that lookup / use

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would pass the repeat the first array, as usual.  Set the var for the repeat to something like 'rowdata'.

For the second array, I would load that into the viewScope (or sessionScope if you need it for a longer time).

When building the repeat, I would use the indexVar of rowData to grab the appropriate member of the second array.

The experts may come up with a more advanced Java data structure but I'm not as familiar with those structures yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show two properties of a list of objects, if one is unique (and in this case the URL will be) a Map is the best option. Here is an example you can use http://mardou.dyndns.org/Privat/osnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?documentId=EB17DF835CCE2F5CC1257C1C0074C823
You can use map.entrySet() or map.keySet() as the source.

If you want more properties, that's the time to start creating Objects based on a class. After all, that's basically what a ViewEntryCollection or DocumentCollection is.

Maps may seem a foreign concept, but they're something all XPages developers are familiar with: the scopes (viewScope, requestScope, sessionScope etc) are all just Maps, with a key and value.